# How to Know Which EventListener will Execute First in Spring

Tags: java, spring, event-listener

I inherited some code that uses multiple Spring EventListeners to handle a specific event. I noticed that in different environments, the EventListeners executed in a different order when an event is published.

For example, say I have 2 EventListeners:

```
@EventListener
@Async
public void doSomethingForEvent(SomeEvent event)
```

and

```
@EventListener
@Async
public void doAnotherThingForEvent(SomeEvent event)
```

In one environment, `doSomethingForEvent` executed before `doAnotherThingForEvent` and in another environment, it was vice versa.

So my question is, is there a way to know what order they will execute in? Is it a random order because of the `@Async` annotation, or is there a way to specify the order?

Comment: There is an `@Order` annotation but I'm not sure if it's valid in this particular scenario.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> It is also possible to define the order in which listeners for a
>   certain event are to be invoked. To do so, add Spring's common @Order
>   annotation alongside this event listener annotation.

As per the `EventListener` document, you can use `@Order` annotation and give different values to define order (lower number have the higher priority)

```
@EventListener
@Order(0)
@Async
public void doSomethingForEvent(SomeEvent event)
```

and

```
@EventListener
@Order(1)
@Async
public void doAnotherThingForEvent(SomeEvent event)
```

In above case, `doSomethingForEvent` will executed first and then `doAnotherThingForEvent` listener always.

Comment: That makes sense. So unless the `@Order` annotation is added, is it safe to assume that the order of execution could be random?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. It would depend on how and which listener will get initialized when Spring context gets loaded.

Comment: Does it actually make sense to have Order and Async annotations together? What would the behavior be in this case?

Answer (score 3):

check the javadoc of `@EventListener`

> It is also possible to define the order in which listeners for a certain event are to be invoked. To do so, add Spring's common @Order annotation alongside this event listener annotation.